# Is it better to use DateTime.MinValue or a nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

If I had a DateTime on a class called "TimeLastAccessed", would it make more sense for this DateTime to be nullable:

```
public DateTime? TimeLastAccessed { get; set }

if (TimeLastAccessed == null) // ... handle it
```

to indicate it has never been accessed or check for DateTime.MinValue

```
public DateTime TimeLastAccessed { get; set; }

if (TimeLastAccessed == DateTime.MinValue) // ... handle it
```

?

Comment: Or should TimeLastAccessed by set to TimeCreated when object is initially created

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It makes more sense to use Nullable. That's the idea of Nullable - to express that a value type has no valid value. To use MinValue is a patch for cases you don't have Nullable.

Comment: It's also too magic. What if someone wanted to express DateTime.MinValue, then it would be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that Nullable<DateTime> is a better choice in the absence of other considerations.

You do however need to consider other systems with which you need to interoperate.

For example:

- if you are exposing your .NET DateTime to COM clients, you won't be able to use Nullable<DateTime>.
- if you are storing the value in a SQL Server database, remember that SQL Server can't store DateTime.MinValue as a DateTime.

Another point to consider is that Nullable can add some complexity for callers of an API: they may need to consider how the null case should be handled.  In some cases it *may* be simpler to use a default value for the null case.  For example, consider a class that exposes a property "ExpiryDate", where a value is needed to indicate that the item never expires.

One approach is to use a `Nullable<DateTime>` with null representing "never expires".  An alternative approach is to use a standard DateTime with `DateTime.MaxValue` representing "never expires".

In this example, the test for "is expired" is simpler for the standard DateTime:

```
if (item.ExpiryDate <= DateTime.Today) ...
```

than for the `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
if (item.ExpiryDate.HasValue && item.ExpiryDate <= DateTime.Today) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How can something that exists never be accessed?  Is your property really something list LastAccessDateByCustomerOrClient?

And in your case I think you want ...HasValue instead of == null in your test.  If you're going to use the class, use the features of it to the fullest.  It probably compiles to nearly the same code but ...