# Overriding DateTime.MinValue causing issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime

We are trying to override the `DateTime.MinValue` in our application, but by doing it we noticed that our Web services are timing-out, following is a sample code. Not sure what is wrong/what we are missing.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     //Introducing this.. Causes timeout of the webservice call...
     typeof(DateTime).GetField("MinValue").SetValue(typeof(DateTime),new DateTime(1900, 1, 1));
     var yesitworks= DateTime.MinValue;
     InitializeComponent();
     ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
     //Below call will timeout...
     var value =client.GetData(10);
}
```

PS: This might not be the best solution for what we are trying resolve but now its more of curiosity as to why it is not working? how is it related.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish by doing this in the first place?

Comment: Nasty... that seems like an awful idea.

Comment: What is your expectation of violating contract that the filed is r/o? I think result you see is perfectly ok - "undefined behavior". Do you want at the same time change value of 1 to be 7 :) ?

Comment: I agree this might not be the best solution... ( might not even use it as a solution... but i am now wondering as to why it is not working)

Comment: If you think about it this is bound to cause issue, imagine if you changed `String.Empty` to `Hello` soooooo much code would fail, Now changing `DateTime.MinValue` could do exactly the same, if the internals of WCF are comparing a value to `DateTime.MinValue` and its not what its expecting you will probably have issues, because these are `Static` properties, they are changing thougout the Application not just your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.MinValue` is a static readonly field. That means that library authors will not expect it to change, and *may* write code that depends on it having the expected value.

Hence, **you should not change the value of `DateTime.MinValue`.**

For example, a library may use it as the default value for a variable:

```
private mostRecentDate= DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (var date in myDates)
{
    if (date > mostRecentDate)
    {
        mostRecentDate= date;
    }
}

// Do something with the most recent date in myDates...
```

In this example, if `myDates` only contained dates earlier than your new value for `DateTime.MinValue`, then this code would set `mostRecentDate` to `DateTime.MinValue` rather than the latest date in `myDates`.

While this rather contrived example may not be good programming practise ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144473/is-it-better-to-use-datetime-minvalue-or-a-nullable-datetime), you could use Nullable instead), it is valid code, whose behaviour would be changed if you changed the value of `DateTime.MinValue`.

The point is that libraries you are using could also be dependant on the value on `DateTime.MinValue`, so changing it could break them. You are llucky in so far as you found out that this introduced a bug early. If you are unlucky, you would not see a problem until your software had gone live and some corner case was hit.

Comment: hmm it does make sense...but was wondering if there was anything known with this dependency... anyway I wont be using it.. will be using the null able types instead

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that there's no way to know which library may have such a dependency without looking at its source code. You are always potentially exposing yourself to this kind of issue whenever you use reflection to modify `readonly` public fields like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.
You didn't tell *why* you wanted to override `DateTime.MinValue`, but I guess the reason is similar to mine:

I have a server written in .NET, which has .NET clients and *(via COM-Interop)* MS Access clients.

The clients pass `DateTime` values, and the server needs to check whether they passed  a "real" value or `DateTime.MinValue`.

My problem was:

- .NET's `DateTime.MinValue` is January 1st of the year **1**
- The smallest possible value for VBA's `Date` type is January 1st of the year **100**

⇒ Checking for `DateTime.MinValue` didn't work when the data was coming from MS Access, because `Date` variables in Access can't hold a date as small as .NET's `DateTime.MinValue`.

At that point I tried to override `DateTime.MinValue` too, and found out it doesn't work.

**My solution was to write an extension method for `DateTime`:**

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool MinValue(this DateTime input)
    {
        // check the min values of .NET *and* VBA
        if (input == DateTime.MinValue || input == new DateTime(100, 1, 1))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

For the code in your question, it would need to look like this:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool MinValue(this DateTime input)
    {
        if (input == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;

// vanilla .NET
bool isMin1 = (theDate == DateTime.MinValue);

// with the extension method
bool isMin2 = theDate.MinValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will be able to change the `DateTime` `MinValue` as it is read only, But if you can **DON'T**

DateTime:

```
public struct DateTime : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, ISerializable, IComparable<DateTime>, IEquatable<DateTime>
{
    public static readonly DateTime MaxValue
    public static readonly DateTime MinValue
    ....
```

Comment: hmm.. I see it does work, However have you thought about the flowon effects of changing this, How much of your code uses datetime compared to all the other code running in your application that uses this value, How do you know the internals of the WCF channel is not using a compare to dateTime.MinValue and is getting the wrong value back. Just a thought